# python で lambda を使い「関数を受け取って関数を返す」関数が作りたい

Tags: python

pythonのlambdaを使った関数 `add_functions(f, g)` があり、
return値を `f(x) + g(x)` としたいのです。たとえば、

```
f = add_functions(lambda x: x*2, lambda x: x + 1)
```

`f(2)` と実行すると結果は以下のようになります。

```
f(2)  # returns (2*2) + (2 + 1) = 7
```

この `add_functions` 関数の中身はどうやって書けばよいでしょう？
教えていただけましたら幸いです。

ヒントには下記のように書かれていました。

> You can directly return a lambda

Comment: ヒントに書かれてある通りかと。`def add_functions(f, g): return lambda x: f(x) + g(x)`

Comment: ありがとうございました！それで解決できました。

Answer (score 3):

ヒントに書いてある通り、ラムダ式自体を返り値にすればよいです。

```
def add_functions(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(x) + g(x)
```

<sub>-- [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38724/python-lambda%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84#comment38977_38724)より。</sub>